# Oracle Forms doesn't completely respect my setting for the background color of an item

Tags: oracle, oracleforms, oracle-ebs

I'm forced to use Oracle Form Builder 10.1.2.3.0. An ideal control I can use in the form for a particular item is a `List Item` using a `List Style` called `Combo Box`.

Using this control, I can use `set_item_property` in a `PRE-FORM` trigger to set the background color of the list items to match the Canvas color.

The default background color of the items is white but that's not the biggest part of the problem. What is a pretty big UI problem is the color of the items after a selection is made: a horrible mustard color. I prefer something more Spartan and certainly something other than screaming "Hey! Look at me!".

When I run the form, everything is good until I choose an item in the list. Afterwards, the background of the selected item is mustard. And each popup of the list shows the items with a mustard background.

I figured I could add triggers to the Item to reset the background color but that didn't work. I created the following triggers to no avail:

```
. WHEN-LIST-CHANGED
. POST-CHANGE
. WHEN-VALIDATE-ITEM
. WHEN-NEW-ITEM-INSTANCE
```

I couldn't find any other trigger names that might be useful.

Is there hope for the code to force my UI preferences?

---

Before any action upon the control:

[image: Before any action upon the control]

---

During the first popup:

[image: First popup]

---

After selecting an item during the first popup:

[image: After selection]

---

Second popup:

[image: Second popup]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `Data Block` containing the item is not a database item, then you can alter that block so that it is not updateable. If you do that, then the mustard color won't be used.

It seems the purpose of the change in color (to mustard) is a visual clue that changes to the database have not been committed. But if the `Data Block` is not a database block, then there's no need for the visual clue because no changes would be possible.

I changed `DML Data Target Type` from `Table` to `None` and the mustard color no longer appears.

The other settings which I didn't change but which might also be relevant are:

```
Database Data Block = No
Query Data Source Type = None
Insert Allowed = No
Update Allowed = No
Locking Mode = Delayed
Delete Allowed = No
Update Changed Columns Only = No
```

Even if it is a database item, you can set the item's update_allowed property to false in its `WHEN-LIST-CHANGED` trigger and set it to property_true in its `WHEN-MOUSE-CLICK` trigger. This is not perfect because if you click on a list item's text instead of the down arrow, then you still get the mustard but at least after you're done, the mustard is gone.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Oracle E-Business Suite they likely have that functionality coded in the template form, which I would guess and say you are likely using.

If you are not using EBS, then you likely have code in your form making this change.  For example, if you have a WHEN-LIST-CHANGED trigger that includes a line of code that looks something like this you will get the behavior you are describing:

```
SET_ITEM_PROPERTY ('LIST1', BACKGROUND_COLOR, 'OLAF1');
```

Comment: Yes, EBS. Setting the color to `OLAF1` makes the control's colors more consistent but it's consistently mustard, which I detest. The definition of this #1 oracle look-and-feel "voodoo" is somewhere in the template and can be modified?

Comment: [This](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/community-paper-forms-look-and-feel-131989.pdf) looks interesting.

Comment: Setting the look-and-feel is only consistent, btw, if OLAF1 is used. If I use OLAF2, 3, or 4, then it's not consistent.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not familiar with the EBS template enough to be able to say how it or other component used by EBS might be making this setting change.  If you are unable to find where this is set, you may be able to override it elsewhere.  You do not have to set the value to an OLAF color.  You could use nearly any color.  Valid values are either one of the OLAF colors (as I previously illustrated) or an RGB value.

Comment: Yes, I have used an explicit rgb color that matches the canvas foreground and, as I mentioned in my post, the behavior is unacceptable. Even if I set the color, it is only respected for a *very* short period of time. By all measures, Oracle has proved itself that it is inferior when it comes to UI.

Comment: @JeffHolt Although I appreciate your opinion ("...inferior when it comes to UI") I cannot say I agree.  Forms (6i and newer) exposes so many ways in which the application developer can customize various aspect of the UI beyond what the product delivered natively.  The problem is that either the developer is unaware of how to do it or the org does make any investment in allowing the developers to do it. Follow on Twitter (@OracleFormsPM) and you will see that many examples have been shared showing how Forms can be made to look more modern. In newer versions this becomes even easier.

Comment: There's a big difference between people who design and build tools and those who build applications using those tools. While both at Oracle are guilty of bad designs, the latter group, EBS, bears a much larger portion of the blame.